# HTML dropdown list not showing 1st item in table

Tags: php, html, sql

I'm working on a forum software right now, and I'm doing the administration panel. I have a part with a dropdown box of all the current forums. It works, but it doesn't show the first forum in the table.

This is my code

```
$select_forums = "SELECT id,name FROM forums";
$run_select_forums = mysql_query("$select_forums");
$row = mysql_fetch_array($run_select_forums, MYSQL_ASSOC);

<form action='index.php' method='post'>
<select>
<?php while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($run_select_forums, MYSQL_ASSOC)) { ?>
<option value="<?php echo $row["id"] ?>" name="selected"><?php echo $row["name"] ?>      
</option>
<?php } ?>
</select><br/>
<input type='submit' name='submitdelete' value='Delete' />
</form>
```

Also I wondered how I can retrieve what item was selected from the list?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It isn't displaying the first one because you're calling `mysql_fetch_array()` once before your `while` loop begins:

```
$select_forums = "SELECT id,name FROM forums";
$run_select_forums = mysql_query("$select_forums");
// Don't call mysql_fetch_array() here...
$row = mysql_fetch_array($run_select_forums, MYSQL_ASSOC);
```

Additionally, you should wrap these values in `htmlentities()` in the attributes and `htmlspecialchars()` outside the attributes to escape them properly as HTML attributes (as well as against XSS attacks)

```
<option value="<?php echo htmlentities($row["id"], ENT_QUOTES) ?>" name="selected"><?php echo htmlspecialchars($row["name"]) ?>      
</option>
```

I understand your `$row['id]` is likely an integer not needing escaping, but it is a good habit to get into.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that worked, I used that htmlentities() and htmlspecialchars() as well.

Answer (score 2):

Your first `$row = mysql_fetch_array($run_select_forums, MYSQL_ASSOC);` pulls the first row from  the table.  When you start your `while` loop the `mysql_fetch_array` picks up with the next row.  The easiest thing to resolve that problem is just not to make that first call.

To retrieve the selected element, give your select tag a name attribute, and it will appear in the $_POST array in the server script that's accepting the submission from the client - in this case index.php, thusly:

with html like

```
<select name="forum">
<option>...</option>
...
</select>
```

in php, `$_POST['forum']` will contain the value between the `<option></option>` tags of the selected item.